# How to cover up the loading time lag in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-cardview, lag

I have made an app in Android Studio which imports data from a website...when I open the app the card views in which the data is to be imported are empty and get loaded after some time. I wanted to know if there is any way in which I can cover it up so that till the time it is being loaded my splash screen stays there. Here is a video showing the lag:

[Card View loading time lag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fb1l8KcXJhJlDGh7W45apRpSG2AWgEQb/view?usp=drivesdk)

**Edit:** Here is the movie Adapter:

```
class MoviesAdapter(
    private var movies: MutableList<Movie>,
    private val onMovieClick: (movie: Movie) -> Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false)
        return MovieViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = movies.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(movies[position])
    }

    fun appendMovies(movies: List<Movie>) {
        this.movies.addAll(movies)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(
            this.movies.size,
            movies.size - 1
        )
    }

    inner class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val poster: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_movie_poster)

        fun bind(movie: Movie) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { onMovieClick.invoke(movie) }
            Glide.with(itemView)
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.posterPath}")
                .transform(CenterCrop())
                .into(poster)
        }
    }
}
```

My main_activity_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/discover"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/popular"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/most_popular_movies" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/popular_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/top_rated"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/highest_rated_movies" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/top_rated_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/upcoming"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/stay_updated" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/upcoming_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/now_playing"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/now_in_Cinemas" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/now_playing_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Api Key:

```
interface Api {

    @GET("movie/popular")
    fun getPopularMovies(
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = 
 "eff7d87eb14cdf1fb273414692d3e3a8",
        @Query("page") page: Int,
    ): Call<GetMoviesResponse>
}
```

Api Loader:

```
api.getPopularMovies(page = page)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<GetMoviesResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<GetMoviesResponse>,
                    response: Response<GetMoviesResponse>,
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val responseBody = response.body()

                        if (responseBody != null) {
                            onSuccess.invoke(responseBody.movies)
                        } else {
                            onError.invoke()
                        }
                    } else {
                        onError.invoke()
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetMoviesResponse>, t: 
    Throwable) {
                    onError.invoke()
                }
            })
```

Is there anything else that I should specify?

Comment: Please tell me if any code is needed, as I could not think of anything else to add.

Comment: Use shimmer effect for card loading animations for data retrieval. Don't use splash screen. If the data retrieval gets long time, the splash screen will be still up which makes users think that "The app is hanged!!" Library Link for shimmer effect: https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/

Comment: I have added the code now, please tell me if anything else is needed...Can you tell me how should I implement the shimmer for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without code it's hard to answer the question, but you could always use a ViewSwitcher that displays a "Loading" state before the data for the cardviews are ready, but holds the space, so the UI won't jump, and then have the Card view displayed once the data is loaded.

Could be something like:

```
sealed class CardData {
object Loading: CardData()
class Info(val items: List<CardInfo>): CardData()
}

fun loadData() {
    viewModel.cardData.observe { cardData ->
        when(cardData) {
          is Loading -> {
            binding.switcher.displayedChild = 0
           }
          is Info -> {
            binding.switcher.displayedChild = 1
            binding.listOfCards.items = cardData.items
          }
    }
}
```

for your specific case:

```
// display the loading view before making the call
binding.switcher.displayedChild = 0
api.getPopularMovies(page = page)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<GetMoviesResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<GetMoviesResponse>,
                    response: Response<GetMoviesResponse>,
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val responseBody = response.body()

                        if (responseBody != null) {
                            onSuccess.invoke(responseBody.movies)
                        } else {
                            onError.invoke()
                        }
                    } else {
                        onError.invoke()
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetMoviesResponse>, t: 
    Throwable) {
                    onError.invoke()
                }
            })

// in your onSuccess()
private void onSuccess(List<Movies> movies) {
 binding.switcher.displayedChild = 1
 listAdapter.items = movies
 listAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
}

// in your onError()
private void onError() {
 binding.switcher.displayedChild = 2 // you can add a third child for errors
}
```

then the XML would be something like (missing attributes):

```
<ViewSwitcher
android:id="@+id/switcher">
<!-- child 0 - loading state -->
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/loader"
/>
<!-- child 1 - movies state -->
<RecyclerView 
android:id="@+id/movies"
/>
<!-- child 2 - error state -->
<TextView 
android:id="@id/error_text"
/>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Comment: Could you tell how it could be implemented...What piece of code should I add?

Comment: without code on which to work on it's hard to tell, but assuming you're using MVVM, i'll write up some pseudocode

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal please check my updated answer and let me know if this is close to what you'd want

Comment: Hello Davy, thank you very much for your help, I think it should work, I will check it out and confirm tomorrow ☺️

Comment: Hi Davy, could you tell what do viewModel, CardInfo and binding refer to here?

Comment: Like how does this code work as I am just a beginner

Comment: you can swap the viewmodel with whatever you're using to load your data, that was just an example, if you add your code for data loading i can adjust my answer to suit whatever you're currently doing

Comment: I have added one of the loader, is it okay?

Comment: could you now please tell the code for my case as I have added the loader?

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal apologies for the delay, please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait in the splash screen, you will need to make that request in the splash screen.

When you have a successful response, you then navigate and pass the data through args/intent extras, assuming this is a different fragment/activity.

Then, when you are setting creating the list adapter you just need to pass this list through the constructor and set wire everything up, like you probably already have.

Hope it helps, but let me know if this wasn't clear enough!

Comment: Yes, could you please explain it further.

Comment: Actually I  don't have a separate activity for the splash screen, rather I have just used the change them in style method, which changes the theme from the splash activity to the main activity in oncreate() method so I think I may not be able to do it your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Splash screen view exactly like your splash screen in your main activity and show it first while loading all the data from the network in the background, once the data arrives, hide this splash screen view and show app's main screen.

You can instead use shimmer effect to show data loading in background.

Comment: Play, I'll try it out and get back to you
Thank you very much for your help ☺️

Comment: Could you tell me how to implement it in my case from the code above?

Comment: Place an image view with your app splash screen logo in the center of the screen and change the background same as the slash screen background, while hiding all other elements of the main activity like your recycler view and other components visibility to hidden. Now, when the main activity opens make your API request and after your receive, your data and set data to the adapter, hide this dummy splash screen and show all components of the main activity including your recycler view.

Comment: Helo Praveen, Thank You for your answerActually as suggested by @Smack Alpha , it would be a better option to go with the shimmer effect rather than the splash activity time delay...so could you tell me the way to implement the shimmer effect in my code?

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal This article explains the implementation of Facebook's shimmer effect in detail https://www.section.io/engineering-education/android-studio-shimmer-loading-effect/